# Setting the meta schemaName for a Sails model from within a controllers action?

Tags: postgresql, sails.js, waterline

I would like to set which schema a model is using via a controller. This is so that I would be able to use one model to populate two different schemas within a single PostgreSQL database.

I thought I would be able to access this value in the controller by using: `sails.models.test.meta.schemaName = 'test2';` but it seems that this is not the case or maybe I am just going about it the wrong way.

In Sails, I have two routes:

```
'get /test1': 'TestController.test1',
'get /test2': 'TestController.test2'
```

And a relative controller:

```
module.exports = {
  data: {
    val1: 'Value 1',
    val2: 'Value 2'
  },
  test1: function (req, res) {
    Test.create( sails.controllers.test.data ).exec(function (err, result){
      res.json(result);
    });
  },
  test2: function (req, res) {
    // Show the current schemaName
    console.log(sails.models.test.meta.schemaName); // outputs: test1
    // Trying to set the schema name
    sails.models.test.meta.schemaName = 'test2';
    // Trying to add a record using a different schema name
    Test.create( sails.controllers.test.data ).exec(function (err, result){
      res.json(result);
    });
  }
};
```

And the relative model:

```
module.exports = {

  connection: 'postgres',

  migrate: 'alter',

  meta: {
    schemaName: 'test1'
  },

  attributes: {
    val1: {type: 'string'},
    val2: {type: 'string'}
  }
};
```

So in the model, the default schema is `test1`. If I visit the route `/test1` in my browser then it will insert the data to the database in the schema `test1`, great.

Now, if I visit the route `/test2` I am expecting the models meta schemaName to be set to `test2` so that when the record is inserted it is inserted to the schema `test2` in the database. This does not happen, it just inserts the value to the schema `test1` as with the previous test.

So then I thought maybe I could set this via [sails.config.models](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-models) however this meta value is not an option there.

Does anyone know how I could achieve this end result?

Any responses would be greatly appreciated, thanks.